# Connecting online while at work?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I am trying to connect my 3DS to my work wifi connection. It is an open wifi network that uses a username/password-based login after initially connecting. On my phone or any device, I pull up a browser and enter the information, then I am good to go until I disconnect.

On my 3DS, it is a bit different. I can connect to the wifi just fine, and even login to the page. However the simple act of re-opening the web browser or attempting to connect online in Pokemon ORAS is re-connecting to the wifi and prompting the login. A minor annoyance in the 3DS's web browser, but a show-stopper for the 3DS.

An alternative option would be to install a certificate on my 3DS that would enable access to the protected wifi network. However I cannot find any information on this. If it matters, I would like to point out that the firewall would not block my game. It is solely the wifi login that is causing me problems.

Is there any way to be able to connect Pokemon ORAS in this manner?

Comment: So this is an issue with your work Wi-Fi, something we may not necessarily know how it's configured or setup.

Comment: If you're able to open a wifi hotspot on your phone/device, I'd do that instead (and connect the 3DS through that). I've had this problem with hotel-based networks, and your setup sounds similar.

Comment: @memescientist Not really. Many wifi hotspots work this way. As long as I stay on the same connection (that I've logged into), then I would be fine. It's the fact that the system wants to disconnect when I'm not actively using it that's causing an issue. It has not just been this connection, but connections at the airport and hotel that have given me issues over the years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3DS attempts to save power by **disconnecting the Wifi** when not directly in use, and reconnecting when you want to use it. This is the standard functionality of the 3DS and cannot be overriden in the settings, or (I assume) without heavy modification of the 3DS OS Software.

Hotels, Cafes and Restaurants use this type of sign-in screen as well, with similar results for 3DS users. This is generally used as a way to get you to agree to the business' terms of use, and serve advertising or other "services". Unfortunately they aren't robust enough to recognise that the same device is connecting twice in a short time period, and attempt to get you to sign in/agree twice.

As a workaround, you should set up your phone as a Wifi Hotspot, and use your Mobile Data connection instead.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept this for now if nobody else has a better workaround.